# 3rd party API Response - Laravel updateOrCreate, delete the rest that previously existed?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm getting data from an outside API. What's the cleanest way to delete existing records that no longer appear from the API after using updateOrCreate? Right now, I have a working method which gets the collection before and forgets the collection record on the API loop. Afterwards, it deletes anything that's left.

This feels hacky and I'm sure there's a better solution. Thanks in advance!

Using: Laravel 7.x

```
$apiPosts = api('....')->json(); // array
$existingPosts = Post::get();

foreach ($apiPosts as $post) {
    Post::updateOrCreate(['id' => $post['id']], [
        'title' => $post['title'],
        'body'  => $post['body'],
        'is_active' => $post['post_visible'],
    ]);

    // Works but ugly
    if ($existingPosts->where('id', $post['id'])->first()) {
        $existingPosts->where('id', $post['id'])->first()->forget();
    } 
}

// Works but ugly
foreach($existingPosts as $post) {
    $post->delete();
}
```

Comment: I don't if this would be any prettier but another option is to get all records that haven't been touched during update process; during update process, `updated_at` would be set to the current timestamp. Depending on how frequently you update, you can select records earlier than today's date (referring to the most recent update data) and then delete those.

Comment: I guess it's faster to put all ids in an array, then run directly in your database (laravel query builder) a `DELETE FROM Posts WHERE id IN (...)` (or update deleted_at if using softdelete). This way you will run only one command, instead of one command for each post.